# How to use regex to match anything from A to B, where B is not preceeded by C

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, escaping

I'm having a hard time with this one. First off, here is the difficult part of the string I'm matching against:

```
"a \"b\" c"
```

What I want to extract from this is the following:

```
a \"b\" c
```

Of course, this is just a substring from a larger string, but everything else works as expected. The problem is making the regex ignore the quotes that are escaped with a backslash.

I've looked into various ways of doing it, but nothing has gotten me the correct results. My most recent attempt looks like this:

```
"((\"|[^"])+?)"
```

In various test online, this works the way it should - but when I build my ASP.NET page, it cuts off at the first ", leaving me with just the a-letter, white space and a backslash.

The logic behind the pattern above is to capture all instances of \" or something that is not ". I was hoping this would search for \", making sure to find those first - but I got the feeling that this is overridden by the second part of the expression, which is only 1 single character. A single backslash does not match 2 characters (\"), but it will match as a non-". And from there, the next character will be a single ", and the matching is completed. (This is just my hypothesis on why my pattern is failing.)

Any pointers on this one? I have tried various combinations with "look"-methods in regex, but I didn't really get anywhere. I also get the feeling that is what I need.

Comment: Your description is a little weird - can you give us a series of example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Where do you get the string `"a \"b\" c"` from? Is it from the debugger in VS or it is the actual string? Seem to me that the actual string is `a "b" c` which does not have the forward slash. It could be the reason your matching pattern is off track.

Comment: can you put a sample data?

Comment: It is the actual string, yes. The quotes will have to be escaped for the pattern to able to recognize the difference. The pattern must also be able to handle multiple instances of escaped quotes, like this:

"a \"b\" c \"d\" e"

... and give this result:

a \"b\" c \"d\" e

The output is always the same; it starts from the first " and ends on the character before the next ", like this:

a \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following expression worked for me:

```
"(?<Result>(\\"|.)*)"
```

The expression matches as follows:

- An opening quote (literal `"`)
- A named capture `(?<name>pattern)` consisting of:

  - Zero or more occurences `*` of literal `\"` or (`|`) any single character (`.`)
- A final closing quote (literal `"`)

Note that the `*` (zero or more) quantifier is non-greedy so the final quote is matched by the literal `"` and not the "any single character" `.` part.

I used ReSharper 9's built-in Regular Expression validator to develop the expression and verify the results:

[image: ReSharper "Validate Regular Expression" feature]

I have used the "Explicit Capture" option to reduce cruft in the output (`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`).

One thing to note is that I am *matching* the whole string, but I am only *capturing* the substring, using a *named capture*. Using named captures is a really useful way to get at the results you want. In code, it might look something like this:

```
    static string MatchQuotedString(string input)
        {
        const string pattern = @"""(?<Result>(\\""|.)*)""";
        const RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture;
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        var matches = regex.Match(input);
        var substring = matches.Groups["Result"].Value;
        return substring;
        }
```

Optimization: If you are planning on using the regex a lot, you could factor it out into a field and use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option, this pre-compiles the expression and gives you faster throughput at the expense of longer initialization.

Comment: The difficult part of this was getting the SO editor to display my pattern text correctly ;-) The syntax highlighting is a bit funky but if you ignore the colours its fine.

Answer (score 1):

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

To match a string like `a \"b\" c`, you need to use following regex declaration:

```
(?:\\"|[^"])+
var rx = Regex(@"(?:\\""|[^""])+");
```

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5C%5C%22%7C%5B%5E%22%5D)%2B&i=a%20%5C%22b%5C%22%20c)

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FUfvR0):

```
var str = "a \\\"b\\\" c";
Console.WriteLine(str);
var rx = new Regex(@"(?:\\""|[^""])+");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(str).Value);
```

Please note the `@` in front of the string literal that lets us use *verbatim* string literals where we have to double quotes to match literal quotes and use single escape slashes instead of double. This makes regexps easier to read and maintain.

If you want to match any escaped entities in your input string, you can use:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*");
```

[See demo on RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D*)*&i=a%20%5C%22b%5C%22%20c)

## UPDATE

To match the quoted strings, just add quotes around the pattern:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"""(?<res>[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*)""");
```

This pattern yields much better performance than Tim Long's suggested regex, see RegexHero test resuls:

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you? If not, could you please post the whole relevant code in your question?

Comment: Please check my updated regex, it is really much better than the one suggested above.